# ec2 elastic inference not reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Good day,

I am currently trying out this tutorial --> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-pytorch-using.html#ei-pytorch-enabled. I have tried to run step 3, but when i checked the status of my elastic inference, it says "not reachable".

The error code I've got is [1,4,1], and I've followed the instructions as per the docs, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastic-inference/latest/developerguide/ei-error-codes.html, yet i've still gotten the same status saying "not reachable".

Anyone experienced the same issues or have any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks